# Is it possible to use html snippets inside of Razor (cshtml) pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, code-snippets

I tried so many ways but I didn't achieve to do it . I can't use html snippets inside of cshtml razor page and it sucks.I don't wanna use VS Code to write ASP.NET MVC because I'm used to use Visual Studio but without snippets its painful  to write html in razor pages. please  help me

I tried to export snippets but it didn't work, downloaded several snippet extensions but it didnt work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the **EmmetVS** extension in visual studio you can find the details on https://github.com/aglasencnik/EmmetVS